# Creating a user from a different website

Tags: users

I need to create users for `example.com`, however I only have access to `dev.example.com`'s dashboard now. Can I still create them for `example.com` from `dev.example.com`'s dashboard? (I see a "website" field on the "Add New User" form but unsure what it's for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot create a user on another install - you need access to the main site (either via WordPress admin or the database).

The "Website" field on the "Add New User" form is nothing more than a profile field for storing information about the user (in this case, a URL).

Comment: Thanks @TheDeadMedic you rock! Couple times I wanted to visit URLs related to you but there isn't any on your profile :/